# Camera Roll vs Photos App, what name is correct?

Tags: ios, photos.app, camera-roll

What is the name of the default native App that stores all photos and pictures on an iOS device? Since iOS 8 it seem to be called "Photos" were before Apple used to call it Camera Roll. Or do I mix something here?

---

**Update:** what is the correct terminology for the default Photos App and for what reasons should the term "Camera Roll" be used?

Comment: It was called Photos before (at least in iOS6). Here's example: http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/ios-6-vs-ios-7-homescreens.jpg

Comment: I think there's a little confusion: there wasn't a "Camera Roll App", there was the "Camera Roll" Album in previous versions of iOS.  Can you update your question to reflect that?

Answer (score 2):

The app has been Photos since the original iPhone OS release, although there has been an album named "Camera Roll" as long as I can remember (iPhone OS 2.0 was my first). See http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0163/8048/files/iOS-Evolutionjpg.jpg?1903
[image]

**Update**: The app can be called Photos or Photos.app or Photos on iOS. Apple seems to just call it Photos, though. The Camera roll refers to the default album *within* Photos. Photographs taken from your camera default to that album—it's the "roll" of images captured by your phone. If you sync photos from another device, they'll be in Photos, but not on the Camera Roll (they'll have their own album(s)). If you have other apps that interact with your photos on-device, they may read from the Camera Roll or may interact with other albums.

**2nd Update**: Having now updated to iOS 8, I now realize that "Camera Roll" has been re-termed "Recently Added" in Photos. This is a better description of what it is, since not all of its entries get there via camera. For example, a photo saved from Facebook's app will on iOS 7 and earlier appear in the "Camera Roll" even though it's not a photo from the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated question is really a matter of opinion with no "correct" answer.  The app is "Photos" and the area that used to be referred to as the "Camera Roll" is now called "Photos." (see the answer from @samh), except that it ALSO contains photos from your other iDevices.

Beyond that, there is no longer a definitive "Camera Roll" in iOS 8, so any usage of it is informal and non-definitive.

Comment: So it was renamed...

Comment: It wasn't really renamed, functionality changed.  It doesn't work like it did in iOS7, the functionality then annoyed me because you had to delete photo's twice, but all the same I'd rather have the camera roll album back.